# Management of buttons functionality and call of a method for bluetooth controller

Tags: android, android-studio

A cordial greeting to all.

I recently joined the community and I'm not very experienced in Android programming, so I'm addressing you with the hope of solving a problem.

I'm developing an Android application that allows me to control, via bluetooth, a robot that uses the mobile phone as a gyro controller with the addition of commands implemented via buttons.
I would like the dispatch of the directional commands to be managed by ToggleButton; that is: only after the pressure and the transition to the READY state, and that the sending is disabled at the next pressure and transition to the NOT READY state.
My problem is being able to call the 'onSensorChanged' gyro sensor method after the first press.

The MainActivity is as follows ():

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor rotationVectorSensor;
private SensorEventListener mListener;

//variabili per misure giroscopio
private TextView assex;
private TextView assey;
private TextView assez;

//variabili per frecce
private ImageView arrowup;
private ImageView arrowdown;
private ImageView arrowleft;
private ImageView arrowright;

//variabili per i bottoni
private Button calibrate;
private Button auto;
private Button stop;
private ToggleButton toggleState;

//variabili per la compensazione della misura della posizione angolare rilevata dal giroscopio
float compensationy;
float compensationz;
float[] orientations = new float[3];

//variabile per associazione deispositivo bluetooth
public UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

//variabili gestione bluetooth
BluetoothSocket mmSocket=null;
BluetoothDevice mmDevice=null;
OutputStream outStream;
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

//variabile visualizzazione stato sensore gioscopico
private TextView sensor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //per visualizzare le misure del giroscopio
    assex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.assexvalue);
    assey = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.asseyvalue);
    assez = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.assezvalue);

    //per visualizzare le immagini delle frecce
    arrowup = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewUp);
    arrowdown = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDown);
    arrowleft = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewLeft);
    arrowright = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewRight);

    //per visualizzare le immagini del bottoni
    calibrate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calibrate);
    auto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Auto);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Stop);
    toggleState = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleState);

    //per visualizzare lo stato del giroscopio
    sensor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensor);

    //controllo presenza sensore giroscopio
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    rotationVectorSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);

    if(rotationVectorSensor==null)
        sensor.setText("Il sensore non è presente");
    else
        sensor.setText("Il sensore è attivo");


    /***************    GESTIONE PULSANTI   ***********************/
    //Pulsante CALIBRATE:
    calibrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            compensationy = -Math.round(orientations[1]);
            compensationz = -Math.round(orientations[2]);
        }
    });

    //Pulsante STOP!:
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            sendMessageBluetooth("N"); //invio comando di STOP!
        }
    });

    //Pulsante AUTO:
    auto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            sendMessageBluetooth("M"); //invio comando di FUNZIONAMENTO AUTOMATICO
        }
    });

    //ToggleState READY!/NOT READY!:  //RIVEDI!!!!!!!
    toggleState.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(!toggleState.isChecked()){
                //dopo la prima pressione del toggle button c'è la scritta NOT READ!
                //alla seconda  pressione del del toggle button entro nella suddetta modalità e
                // non invio alcun carattere
            }
                /*le frecce sono disabilitate*/
            else {
                //sul bottone inizialmente c'è la scritta READY!
                //alla prima pressione del del toggle button entro nella suddetta modalità e
                // chiamo la funzione 'onSensorChanged'
                //invio comandi frecce
            }
        }
    });

    /***************************************************************/

    /***************** Gestione e controllo connessione bluetooth **********************/
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null){
        // IL BLUETOOTH NON E' SUPPORTATO
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BlueTooth non supportato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())//controlla che sia abilitato il devices
            //  NON E' ABILITATO IL BLUETOOTH
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BlueTooth non abilitato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else {
            mmDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("00:12:12:24:17:08");
            try {
                mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                ;
            }
            try {
                mmSocket.connect();
                outStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (IOException closeException) {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ceXC) {
                    ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, rotationVectorSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(
            rotationMatrix, sensorEvent.values);

    // Remap coordinate system
    float[] remappedRotationMatrix = new float[9];
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix,
            SensorManager.AXIS_Y,
            SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X,
            remappedRotationMatrix);

    // Convert to orientations
    SensorManager.getOrientation(remappedRotationMatrix, orientations);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        orientations[i] = (float)(Math.toDegrees(orientations[i]));
    }

    float valuey = Math.round((orientations[1])  + compensationy);
    float valuez = Math.round((orientations[2])  + compensationz);

    assex.setText(Float.toString(Math.round(orientations[0])));
    assey.setText(Float.toString( valuey ));
    assez.setText(Float.toString( valuez ));;

    if(valuey > 20 ) {
        arrowup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        arrowdown.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sendMessageBluetooth("W");
    }
    else if(valuey < -20 ) {
        arrowdown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        arrowup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sendMessageBluetooth("S");
    }
    else if (valuez > 20) {
        arrowright.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        arrowleft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sendMessageBluetooth("D");
    }
    else if (valuez < -20) {
        arrowleft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        arrowright.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sendMessageBluetooth("A");
    }
    else if (valuez > -20 && valuez < -15 || valuey < 20 && valuey > 15|| valuey > -20 && valuey < -15|| valuez < 20 && valuez > 15 ){
        sendMessageBluetooth("P");
    }
    else {
        arrowup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        arrowdown.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        arrowleft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        arrowright.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
    ;
}

public void sendMessageBluetooth(String message) {
    if (outStream == null)
        return;

    byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

    try {
        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        ;
    }
}
```

}

This code is my version 2.0, developed starting from a previous version 1.0 in which the ToggleButton is not present and the directional commands are sent with the inclination of the mobile phone. If I need I'll load it.

Answer (score 0):

How do you eat an elephant?... One piece at the time.Therefore, I would advice to first separate the code inside MainActivity into their own reusable classes. It will help you to debug better, to develop better, and it will be easier to get help.

For example, these are the pieces that you could split the code:

- Sensor class that implements SensorEventListener
- Bluetooth class that takes care of the bluetooth
- MainActivity should only take care of the UI
- Core class should be between the MainActivity and the other classes. It should hold your "business logic" and keep the "states" of your program.

Now, answering your comment:

> My problem is being able to call the 'onSensorChanged' gyro sensor method after the first press.

Check this StackOverFlow post for a possible answer: [onSensorChanged() not calling for Gyroscope Sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716078/onsensorchanged-not-calling-for-gyroscope-sensor)

> The reason it is not firing is because you did not register for callbacks for your given activity when sensor changes occur. Refer here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html .

Try that and lets see if that helps you out.